# dd command not working when copying data to remote server

Tags: cloud

I used the dd command to copy the mbr from an aws instance to azure instance and command was

```
ssh hostname@my.ip.address "sudo dd if=/dev/sda " | sudo dd of=/dev/sdc     bs=512 count=1.
```

It shows successful execution but as i am copying the mbr the partition table should be changed too but it doest reflect into azure instance .In azure it shows no partition on disk /dev/sdc when there is a partition on /dev/sda.

Can i get help regarding the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution to this already needed brackets in the command.The following command will work
    sudo dd if=/dev/xvda | (ssh username@ip_address sudo dd of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1)